# handle messages from watchOS App always in AppDelegate

Tags: ios, iphone, appdelegate, watchos-2

When my iOS app is open and it get´s a message from my watchOS App it´s handled within the class of the actual displayed ViewController.
If the iOS app isn´t open it´s handled the message in the AppDelegate.

I want that the message is always handling in the AppDelegate otherwise I should implement my handling in all classes.

Is there a way to do that?
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You should consider to implement a class that handles the communication with the counterpart. Then keep an instance of it in the `AppDelegate` only.

Comment: And this is a subclass of?

Comment: Subclass of nothing (or `NSObject` if you prefer). You should implement only the WCSession logic in it

Comment: Where should I define the session? I think it must be before using the function `didReceiveMessage`

Comment: You have to define a `WCSession` to get the method `didReceiveMessage` called